# How to view the stack trace of errors that occur while running an app with an Android emulator (without Android Studio)

Tags: android, gradle, command-line

I am currently learning how to develop apps on Android in Java, and I'm right now I'm attempting to build and install programs from the command line (without Android Studio). Right now, I'm using gradle to build and install a program to an emulator. The problem now is that my app is crashing immediately and I have no idea why. The gradle command `gradle installDebug` just installs the app and terminates. The emulator command `emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28 -verbose` similarly gives me a bunch of useful information at startup but is completely silent while my app crashes. I'm wondering how exactly I'm supposed to see the stack trace resulting from the crash.

Answer (score 0):

There's a program bundled into the Android SDK (or maybe it's installed automatically by Android Studio, I'm not sure) called the Android Device Monitor. By default, it can be accessed by running `./pathToSdk/tools/monitor`. And from there you have the same windowed thing that used to be used in older versions of Android Studio. It's not a pure command-line solution, and it may require installing Android Studio beforehand, but it works very well.